# Confusion related to Nested Try Except in Python

Tags: python, nested, try-except

```
def FancyDivide(numbers, index):
try:
    try:
        denom = numbers[index]
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            numbers[i] /= denom
    except IndexError, e:
        FancyDivide(numbers, len(numbers) - 1)
    else:
        print "1"
    finally:
        print "0"
except ZeroDivisionError, e:
    print "-2"
```

Function Output

```
>>> FancyDivide([0, 2, 4], 0)
0
-2
```

I expect only -2 as the answer but why 0.  According to me ZeroDivisionError should be caught by last except statement and therefore the answer should be -2. Confused. Please Help.

Comment: You're confusing `finally` (always executed) with `else` (executed in the absence of an exception).

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` block will execute regardless of if an `Exception` is thrown or not.

With your code throwing the exception inside the nested `try`, the associated `finally` block will execute before the outer `except`.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the ZeroDivisionError *will* be caught by the outer `try` block, but `finally` clauses are **always** executed before leaving their respective `try` block (even when an exception is raised within it).

So in your case, the inner `try` raises the exception, the inner `finally` is executed, then the outer `try` catches the exception.

More info here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions